# Check md5sum of all files in a directory in python

Tags: python, path

I am having too many duplicate songs on my hard-disk  and i want to remove duplicates.What i want to do is write a python program to check md5sum of all files and remove file with similar md5sum but keeping at least 1 copy.The issue i am facing is that music files have spaces in their name and path is not evaluated correctly.Below is my code to check md5sum

```
__author__ = 'akthakur'

import os
import subprocess

def listFiles(location):
    for name in os.listdir(location):
        path=os.path.join(location,name)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
         listFiles(path)
        else:
          cmd= 'md5sum ' + path
          print(cmd)
          fp= os.popen(cmd)
          print(fp.read())
          fp.close()

listFiles("E:\offwork")
```

I want  to  just pass path of my e drive  to "listFiles" function and it should provide me md5sum off all the  files in all directories recursively.

Spaces in file names are causing serious trouble,is there any way of dealing with the same

Comment: Can you please be more specific what "serious trouble" you mean? I assume the problem is with calling the subprocess. Try `cmd = 'md5sum "' + path + '"'`.

Comment: Thanks Cu3p042 ,why didn't that came to my mind.I think i was too lazy to think that.

Comment: Glad to help out. Since this seems to have solved your problem, I have created an actual answer, so you can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `md5sum` as an external program. That means a file path needs to be escaped with quotes if it contains a space. Please change

```
cmd= 'md5sum ' + path
```

to

```
cmd = 'md5sum "' + path + '"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of args in popen

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

```
args = path.split(' ')

fp= os.popen(['md5sum']+args)
```